# Yii separate log files for each user

Tags: logging, yii

I want to store my log messages in separate log files for each user.
My current config is like:

```
'log'=>array(
'class'=>'CLogRouter',
'routes'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
        'logFile'=>'custom.log.u1',
        'categories'=>'error.*',
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
        'logFile'=>'custom.log.u2',
        'categories'=>'error.*',
    ),
    ...
))
```

but my user are more than 2 and the log file name should set dynamically ...
how can i do that ... ?

Comment: do you want to store different folder or file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I can think of is to extend `CFileLogRoute` and override some of the functions:

make a php file named `MyLog` in a folder that gets autoloaded like components

```
class MyLog extends CFileLogRoute
{
    public $filderName;

    public function getLogFile()
    {
        return parent::getLogFile() . (int)Yii::app()->user->id;
    }

    public function setLogFile($value)
    {
        parent::setLogFile($value . (int)Yii::app()->user->id);
    }
}
```

then in your config:

```
'log'=>array(
'class'=>'CLogRouter',
'routes'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'MyLog',
        'categories'=>'error.*',
    ),
    ...
))
```

Comment: Hi, I also want to create separate log files for each module in my project, can you please help me for the same